# If a sports car has more torque than a truck would it win in a pull off?

Tags: torque

Lets say a sports car is hooked to a truck but the sports car is rated at 300 foot lbs and the truck is rated at 150 foot lbs. Which would win? how does gearing come into play? I would assume the sports car RPMs would need to be too high to then keep traction.

Comment: Depends on the gearing. If the truck had a really low granny gear then the torque of the motor would be converted to a lot more torque at the rear wheels.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't just about torque.  The maximum pulling force of each vehicle comes from the maximum amount of friction that the vehicle's tires can exert on the pavement.  At that maximum friction force, the tires will begin to slip, and the tire surface will change from using static friction, to using kinetic friction, which is known to be less than the maximum static friction.  That maximum amount of static friction is the product of the static friction coefficient of the tire/road surface, and the downward force that is being applied to the tires.  This means that you need to evaluate the maximum amount of static friction for each vehicle before you "place a bet" on the winner of this tug-of-war.

Comment: Good point, but you are forgetting the power. With enough friction, the most powerful machine (properly geared) wins. So it is a combination of friction, power, and gearing.

Comment: @safesphere, you used the correct qualifier.  "With enough friction"; friction cannot be ignored, and it is unsound to assume that the vehicle with the most power also has the most friction with the road surface.